# Getting tracking information for a Git branch

Tags: bash, git, branch, remotes

How can I get tracking information (i.e. remote and branch name) about a specific local Git branch, preferably in one command? There seem to be many ways to do this, e.g.

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name branch_name@{upstream}
```

However, it returns the upstream in the form `'origin/branch_name'`, which makes it difficult to figure out the separate parts (e.g. when remote or branch name contains `'/'`). Is there more reliable solution, preferably using a single Git command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@RomainValeri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057485/romainvaleri) in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424099/10155936) suggested this command to display the tracking information.

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:short)" refs/heads/<yourBranch>
```

However, if you want to get rid of the slash then you can do this

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:remotename) %(upstream:lstrip=-1)"  \ 
# Insert your separator here                     ^
refs/heads/<yourBranch>
```

From [git-docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-upstream),

> **upstream**
>
> The name of a local ref which can be considered “upstream” from the
>   displayed ref. Respects :short, **:lstrip** and :rstrip in the same way as
>   refname above ...
>
> For any remote-tracking branch %(upstream), **%(upstream:remotename)** and
>   %(upstream:remoteref) refer to the name of the remote and the name of
>   the tracked remote ref, respectively. In other words, the
>   remote-tracking branch can be updated explicitly and individually by
>   using the refspec %(upstream:remoteref):%(upstream) to fetch from
>   %(upstream:remotename).

More on [**lstrip**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-refname),

> If lstrip= < N > (rstrip= < N >) is appended, strips < N > slash-separated
>   path components from the front (back) of the refname (e.g.
>   %(refname:lstrip=2) turns refs/tags/foo into foo and
>   %(refname:rstrip=2) turns refs/tags/foo into refs). **If < N > is a
>   negative number, strip as many path components as necessary from the
>   specified end to leave -< N > path components (e.g. %(refname:lstrip=-2)
>   turns refs/tags/foo into tags/foo** and %(refname:rstrip=-1) turns
>   refs/tags/foo into refs). When the ref does not have enough
>   components, the result becomes an empty string if stripping with
>   positive < N >, or it becomes the full refname if stripping with
>   negative < N >. Neither is an error.

---

Some examples :

- Format : `"%(upstream:remotename):%(upstream:lstrip=-1)"`

  Output :  `<remote-name>:<branch-name>`
- Format : `"%(upstream:remotename) %(upstream:lstrip=-1)"`

  Output :  `<remote-name> <branch-name>`

---

If the branch name includes a slash, then `lstrip` won't work. Instead `remoteref` can be used.

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:remotename) %(upstream:remoteref)" refs/heads/<yourBranch>
```

The output is in this format : `<remote-name> refs/heads/<branch-name>`

To remove `refs/heads/` from the output, pipe the above command to this

```
sed 's/refs\/heads\///g'
```

Comment: I think this won't work when a branch name contains slashes, e.g. `'foo/bar/baz'` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the built-in `-v` (verbose) or even `-vv` (very verbose) flag to get this from `git branch` output. You might also just grep the branch name to focus on what you wanted :

```
git branch -vv | grep <branchName>
```

Depending on what exactly you want to get, maybe also consider using the plumbing tool :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:short)" refs/heads/<yourBranch>
```

and make it an alias for convenience

```
git config --global alias.get-rem '!f() { git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:short)" refs/heads/$1; }; f'

# then just
git get-rem branch_name
```

---

**Edit :** For the very short part (i.e. `"branch"` instead of either `"refs/remotes/origin/branch"` or even `"origin/branch"`), you can use `%(upstream:lstrip:-1)` instead of `%(upstream:short)`

Comment: Doesn't this also return the remote branch in the form `<remote>/<branch_name>` (thus, difficult to parse) ?

Comment: @planetp `%(upstream:short)` gives `origin/feature` where `%(upstream)` would have given `refs/remotes/origin/feature`

Comment: @planetb OK sorry I get it, the part you want stripped is not only `refs/remotes/` but also `origin/`